# Can the other side of the observable universe be seen as a black hole?

Tags: black-hole, observable-universe, event-horizon

When looking at the objects near the horizon of the observable universe, the objects seem to emit radiation that is red-shifted. Time seems to advance at a slower rate than our own and at the horizon itself time seems to stand still. It looks as if all matter that moves away from us gets piled up out there.
This is reminiscent of the horizon of a black hole. The matter that falls into the hole seems to get piled up at the event horizon. Behind the horizon of the hole, there is mass. This is also the case for the horizon of the visible universe. Behind it, there is the mass of the rest of the universe.

Can we say that we look at a black hole when observing the limits of observable spacetime? A kind of "inversed" black hole, that is? By which I mean that we are living *inside* a black hole, from which we can see nothing escaping it, not even light.

Comment: This is essentially an application of the holographic principle in theories of quantum gravity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle